# Combine all selected columns to one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-concat

I'm running out of solution to combine below table. Kindly assist. Thanks.

```
InvoiceNo FileNo
00001      A001
00002      A001
```

Above is the table that i select, what i want to show in my list is like below.

```
InvoiceNo       FileNo
00001,00002      A001
```

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: you can use pivoting if it's sql server

Comment: What's your dbms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sql-server version**

you can use `STUFF` function.

```
SELECT  STUFF((
          SELECT ',' + InvoiceNo
          FROM T
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') as 'InvoiceNo'      ,FileNo
FROM T
GROUP BY FileNo
```

sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5028e/8

---

**Oracle version**

you can use `LISTAGG` function.

```
SELECT 
    LISTAGG(InvoiceNo, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY InvoiceNo)  InvoiceNo,
    FileNo  
FROM t
GROUP BY FileNo
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5028e/2

**[Results]**:

```
|    INVOICENO | FILENO |
|--------------|--------|
| 00001, 00002 |   A001 |
```

Answer (score 1):

if mysql then use group_concat function

```
SELECT FileNo,GROUP_CONCAT(InvoiceNo) as InvoiceNo
FROM your_table
GROUP BY FileNo;
```